Consistent delay after page creation in svelte
I'm trying to create a new page after submitting a form to the server then redirecting the client to this new page. After redirecting, I get an error 404 and after a refresh it work (at least in dev, i didn't tried in production). So I add a delay to the redirect, which... it work half of the time.
Here the content of my +page.svelte
<form method="POST" action="?/create">
    <label>
        Title
        <input name="title" type="text">
    </label>
    <label>
        URL
        <input name="URL" type="text">
    </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

And of +page.server.js
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    create: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData()
        //const gameTitle = data.get('title')
        const gameURL = data.get('URL')

        const fileTemplate = '<script>\n    import Template from "../template.svelte";\n</script>\n\n<p>I am the page file</p>\n<Template />'

        fs.mkdir(`./src/routes/(games)/${gameURL}/`, (error) => { console.error(error) })
        fs.writeFile(`./src/routes/(games)/${gameURL}/+page.svelte`, fileTemplate, (error) => { console.error(error) })
        
        setTimeout(redirect(303, `/${gameURL}`), 3000)
        
        return { success: true }
    },
    delete: async (event) => { // TODO: delete selected page },
    update: async (event) => { // TODO: change options on a file already created }
};

This should add a folder with the name chosen, and then a svelte file with content alredy in.
It should look like this in routes folder :
routes
| - (games)
  | - [This should be gameURL]
    | - +page.svelte

atm here is the content of +page.svelte
<script>
    import Template from "../template.svelte";
</script>

<p>I am the page file</p>
<Template />

In theory template.svelte should only give out the shape of the page and all other +page.svelte within folder should have colors and image but that just for context.
Thanks for any help ^^.

SvelteKit is not supposed to be used like this, and I'm fairly certain this will never work when you build it for production.
Using it in dev mode I guess could work (I don't see any reason for why the dev server should make a distinction between you manually creating a new +page.svelte file and code in your app doing it), but it's still not intended to be used like this, so I would avoid it.
I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but read up on [slug] in the docs, that probably something you need to use to be able to achieve what you want.
You also seems to want users to be able to create new games using forms? For that, you need to be able to store these games somehow on the server-side, for example in a database.

I want to try to copy the principle of itch.io for personal use, i.e. to create pages without having to code but with the possibility of changing colors etc.... [slug] might work, but how can I store the data?

Explaining how to do server-side web development is a way too long topic for a StackOverflow answer, but you can for example use the npm package better-sqlite3 to store your data (games) in a relational database on the server. But note that when you later want to run this on a server, you will need to run it as a Node.js app, so you need to host it on a server where you can run Node.js apps.
